# Sniffing with Wireshark Monitor mode not available

Tags: wireshark, sniffing

So I want to sniff WiFi traffic in my network (not the device wireshark is running on) while being connected so no decrypting with PSK.
My WiFi card does support Monitor mode and Injections, however neither Wireshark or tshark let me use the Monitor mode. In Wireshark there's no checkbox to enable it.

Sniffing in monitor mode without being connected works fine, but I want to avoid the decrypring part for simplicity.

How do I get Wireshark to monitor anyways?

Comment: Not all cards support monitor mode while connected. You may have to use a different card. Please edit your question to include the details of your card and OS.

Comment: Have a look at https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/CaptureSetup/WLAN if you haven't already.